# How to effectively manage many sql servers

Tags: sql-server

I have around few hundreds SQL servers and found difficult to organize them in kind of structure.

Do you know if there is kind of tool that would allow me managing SQL Servers connections similar to what Remote Desktop Connection manager does for Windows OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Group your connections in Object Explorer using Server Groups.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg313740.aspx